# In official android.jar library i've not Fragment and FragmentList classes

Tags: android, fragment

In official android.jar library i've not Fragment and FragmentList classes, where i can find them?
Thank u very much, guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include fragments in your projects you need to add the compatibility package jar for your project which is a library of api's that was developed for honeycomb. If should be in your sdk folder, for eg in path like

```
E:\Softwares\Android\android-compatibility\v4\android-support-v4.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

In [Compatibility package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html), or in later android SDK (3.0 and higher).